# Do $Cov(X,Y)=0$ and $EX=EY=0$ imply $Cov(X^2,Y^2)=0$?

Tags: probability

Prove or disprove the following:
Let X and Y be uncorrelated univariate random variables with $EX=EY=0$, then $$V(XY)=V(X)V(Y)$$

After doing many steps, I think it suffices to show $Cov(X^2,Y^2)=0$. But not sure if this is guaranteed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $X\sim U(-1,1)$, $Y=|X|-1/2$. Then $\mathsf{E}X=\mathsf{E}Y=\mathsf{E}XY=0$. However,
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X^2,Y^2)=\mathsf{E}X^2Y^2-\mathsf{E}X^2\mathsf{E}Y^2=\frac{1}{30}-\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{180}.
$$